# Thumbnail Image Rounded Corners w CSS (or any other good method)

Tags: loop, images, css, post-thumbnails

I've been researching how to display thumbnails with rounded images, but every solution ends up running out of gas.

One trick I tried was wrapping the thumbnail in a division with the same size and shape, showing the image, but with CSS of `opacity:0` so that the actual image doesn't show. What shows is the background image for the division, and it's this, also that is styled using:

`border-radius: 15px;`

(plus other browser related hacks)

To do this on WordPress, I'm going to have to use inline styles, it seems, to give the same div the right background image using

```
the_post-thumbnail()
```

Seems to lead to nowhere because I don't see a way to pull just the image url in a way that I can call within

```
<div style="   ";
```

Any ideas?

I'm trying to avoid Javascript, but if that's the only way...

[Here's a link to the method I mentioned](http://how2designweb.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/how-to-make-rounded-corner-images-using-css3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the thumbnail URL with [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) and [get_post_thumbnail_id](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id):

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
echo $src[0];
```